# Can you put the BitTorrent cache on a USB flash drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, bittorrent, cache

I wonder if there's any way to improve BitTorrent performance by putting any cache on a USB stick, like the ReadyBoost in Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

ReadyBoost was an improvement because it put files in sequence on the flash drive; therefore, it would sometimes be faster than an HDD. 'Sometimes' because it offered you a test to see if ReadyBoot would improve your boot time, and, sometimes, it told you not to bother.  Now, [HDDs are faster than USB2 flash drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384826/is-putting-swap-on-a-usb2-flashdrive-practical).

Your cache files are not in linear sequence, in the order they must be accessed to hasten startup. And, by now, odds are you have a system drive which is faster than the typical HDD when ReadyBoost was hot stuff.

Comment: Not too sure how Windows BitTorrent caches work, but wouldn't an external SSD that was devoted just to the cache be useful?

Comment: @JakeGould He didn't ask for that; he asked about an external USB flash drive, which IIRC are slower.

Comment: I realize that is what the question is about; USB flash drives. But since low capacity SSD drives —like 64GB to 128GB — are relatively cheap, just an idea.

Comment: @JakeGould - ReadyBoost is basically useless (can't even be used) after you have a certain amount of system memory.  You basically can only use it if Windows thinks it should be used, more memory, but more memory won't make Bittorrent faster.

Comment: @Ramhound But for file storage and random access SSDs are definitely faster than many hard drives? This is mainly an idea.

Comment: @JakeGould Depends on the USB flash drive capabilities and whether they plug it into a USB3 port or a slower USB port.One Size Does Not Fit All when it comes to USB.